# Swift: How to view the values of variables displayed in Xcode's watch window?

Tags: xcode, swift

Simple question - how can you view the values of variables in Xcode's watch window when using Swift?

Here's an example, see how mdn has the value 2067134273 yet its not possible to view that in the watch window (ObjectiveC.NSObject doesn't expand to anything).

[image]

I thought this might be due to the fact that its an optional, however its not that straightforward because look at the display of onss which is displayed as "Optional NSString", its possible to view that and its an NSString?, while nss which is a non optional NSString doesn't have its value displayed.

Here's their declarations:

```
var nss:NSString = "NSString"
var ss = "Swift string"
var onss:NSString? = "Optional NSString"
```

So when debugging with Xcode how can the values of mdn and nss be viewed, and preferably be made to be displayed automatically without having to use the console?

Comment: try something like `expr -l objc -- mdn`

Comment: The console doesn't like that, it says mdn is an undeclared identifier (though po mdn is ok, but doesn't display its content). Anyway Swift is a step forwards, but having to type to display its values is a step backwards IMO.

Comment: I say this is a bug in lldb it is not smart to print `NSString`. also try `expr -l objc -- (id)(0x POINTER_VALUE)`

Comment: "expr -l objc -- (id) (0x00000001702261c0)" (where 0x00000001702261c0 is the value of mdn displayed in the watch window) displays "(id) $0 = 0x00000001702261c0". "expr -l objc -- (id)(0x mdn)" says invalid suffix x.

Comment: just an thought about that line `if mdn!.lenght >= 10 { ... }`, that will cause a direct crash if the `mdn` cannot be unwrapped.

Comment: why so compilcated with all the expr and flags? you can do `po myVar` and it prints the variable value right away

Answer (score 8):

Xcode 6 beta 4 shows values of variables of `NSString` and `NSString?` types:

[image]

Nevertheless if you may need to see details for some other type even from some third-party framework that you cannot alter then you can implement `debugQuickLookObject` method and return custom description. In case of third-party lib you should wrap it in extension. For `NSString` it will be:

```
extension NSString {
    func debugQuickLookObject() -> AnyObject {
        return self
        // return "Here is debug value: \(self)"
    }
}
```

To preview it, just select the item in watch window and hit `spacebar`:

[image]

Comment: App called LICEcap. It is free, you can download it at http://www.cockos.com/licecap/

Comment: This is a great answer. It's to bad there isn't a runtime debug tool the [intermediate window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy.aspx) in Visual Studio for .net apps. That would make life 10x easier.

Comment: A debugger where you can't see object variables?  What year is this?