# Swift: Print(object) in console not showing variable properties like Objective-C for NSObjects

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, swift

I'm trying to use the console debugger (LLDB) to print out some variables but quite often the output doesn't display any of the variable's properties:

`p _myObject` or `po _myObject` (neither work)

yields

```
(myApp.SomeEntity) $R2 = 0x00007fa4aad2fda0 {
  myApp.SomeParentEntity = {
    CoreData.NSManagedObject = {
      ObjectiveC.NSObject = {}
    }
  }
}
```

ditto for other `NSObjects`, is there a special way you have to print out `NSObjects` in Swift?

Comment: This answer certainly helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/25065381/404409 I've still not found a replacement for `po`, but selecting the object in the split pane and pressing space does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with XCode 6 and Swift project.

I finally found the explanation : On the bottom left of the Debugger console your have a Menu List with 3 options :

- **All Output**,
- **Debugger Output** and
- **Target Output**.

To see `po < variableName >` you have to select **All output** or **Debugger Output**.

Answer (score 1):

Correct way:

```
po _myObject
```

po - print object.
You can read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/gdb_to_lldb_transition_guide/document/Introduction.html)

Comment: Neither `po` or `p` work that way w/NSObject in Swift